# Where do the parameters come from for action that gets invoked by Html.RenderAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I tried to use the debugger but I can't seem to get anywhere. I can't step into Html.RenderAction(), it's in my master page.

I read that it gets the value "automatically" through routing. How does that work?

```
// "Nav" is the name of the controller housing the "Menu" action
// This is called in Site.Master
<% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>

// where does "category" come from?
public ViewResult Menu(string category)
{
}
```

I made this according to a book, but I can't find an explanation in there. The category supposedly comes from the URL automatically into the parameter.

On a related note: Do you advise to download the source code for MVC to work properly, or would that complicate my efforts more than it would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Category parameter is being picked up from the following routing entry

```
        routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}", // Matches ~/Football or ~/AnythingWithNoSlash
                        new { controller = "Products", action = "List", page = 1 }
        );
```

so if /Football is entered then it is supplied as a parameter to the ViewResult Menu in the

which in turn calls

```
    public ViewResult List(string category, int page = 1)
    {
        var productsToShow = (category == null)
                ? productsRepository.Products
                : productsRepository.Products.Where(x => x.Category == category);

        var viewModel = new ProductsListViewModel {
            Products = productsToShow.Skip((page - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToList(),
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = productsToShow.Count()
            },
            CurrentCategory = category
        };
        return View(viewModel); // Passed to view as ViewData.Model (or simply Model)
    }
```

so later within the view master when the render action is called

```
    <% Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav"); %>
```

it can pick up on the category parameter in the route i.e. {category}

```
    public ViewResult Menu(string category)
    {
        // Just so we don't have to write this code twice
        Func<string, NavLink> makeLink = categoryName => new NavLink
        {
            Text = categoryName ?? "Home",
            RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary(new {
                controller = "Products", action = "List",
                category = categoryName, page = 1
            }),
            IsSelected = (categoryName == category)
        };

        // Put a Home link at the top
        List<NavLink> navLinks = new List<NavLink>();
        navLinks.Add(makeLink(null));

        // Add a link for each distinct category
        var categories = productsRepository.Products.Select(x => x.Category);
        foreach (string categoryName in categories.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
            navLinks.Add(makeLink(categoryName));

        return View(navLinks);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nicholas: One more question: I understand why Products.List() gets called with the right parameter. I also understand now why NavController.Menu() is getting called. But why is the NavController.Menu() getting called with the correct parameter {category}? The routing entry specified "ProductsController" and "List" as default action to be used. Nowhere is there any mention of the NavController and the "Menu" action in my routing instructions. (referring to your first source code quote. There is no "Nav" or "Menu" in there, but the category is still getting passed on.

Comment: @Blub - it is getting called with the parameter,  as the parameter is available via the url - just as if it was index.asp?category=chess and you had a method that called Request.QueryString("category"). If in the routing you changed routes.MapRoute(null, "{category}", to routes.MapRoute(null, "{catgory}", then when you step through the code you will see category being null.

Comment: @Nicholas: So, Request.QueryString() is always getting called *automatically* then, right? Because of the MVC framework. Whatever action I could ever write, it will get called to get url parameters?

Comment: @Blub - Steve says at the top of page 147 - it can demand to be told the current category as a parameter to its Menu() action method - by adding it as a parameter called category.

Comment: @Nicholas: It just says, that the controller can "demand" to be told the current category as a parameter to its Menu() action method. Not how it works. But it's fine, I guess I could aswell look into the framework source code. A tad too much automagical stuff happening in MVC :/ (the unit test on that site obviously just works because you supply the category yourself. Not that obvious if it comes somehow from the url)

Comment: Ah okay, I think I get it. The "object defaults" parameter in MapRoute doesn't mean that only the named controller and action will be used, but that it will be used first. There isn't an explanation anywhere what happens when the object defaults are not satisfied, so there was my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The `Html.RenderAction` call renders the action with method name `"Menu"`, in the controller `"Nav"`.

The routing file contains patterns for how to populate method parameters (and resolve overloaded actions). The routing file is usually found in `~/Global.asax`, in the `RegisterRoutes` method. This file should contain multiple calls to `RouteCollection#MapRoute`, which maps a certain URL pattern to a new object with particular variables.

Your routes must include a single string mapping somewhere, which captures anything without a slash into a variable called `category`. That is then passed to the `Menu` action method.

**Addendum:** Try looking [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs) for more information.

Comment: As for the "automatically through routing" business, that refers to incoming URLs only. If `Html.RenderAction` is called in the master page, that's not an incoming URL request. So for the purposes of `Html.RenderAction`, you can forget about routing.

Comment: What exactly is an incoming URL? And the docs say, that Html.RenderAction()'s second string parameter is the controller name. In my solution, I'm never getting "Nav" in my category variable, but the last part of my URL. (for example: www.example.com/trees -> leads to "trees" in the category parameter) I still don't understand why.

Comment: @Blub: Ah hell, I was completely wrong in my original answer. Sorry! I've edited it in the hope that it will make more sense.